# Add sum to do a negative based on cell.offset vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to add a formula to a selected cell if column A matches a selected criteria.

The only part I cannot get to work is the following bit of code.

```
cell.Offset(0, 7).Value = "=SUM(" & cell.Offset(0, 6) & ",-(" & cell.Offset(0, 8) & "," & cell.Offset(0, 5) & "))"
```

If I was to type the formula manually it would appear like this

```
=Sum(G2-I2)-F2
```

Its easy to add just that code but it wouldnt update the row number to the current row.

Any help would be apprecaited.

Thanks
Al

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
cell.Offset(0, 7).Formula = "=SUM(" & _
                            cell.Offset(0, 6).Address & _
                            "-" & _
                            cell.Offset(0, 8).Address & _
                            ")-" & _
                            cell.Offset(0, 5).Address
```

Or this perhaps?

```
cell.Offset(0, 7).Formula = "=SUM(" & _
                            cell.Offset(0, 6).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False) & _
                            "-" & _
                            cell.Offset(0, 8).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False) & _
                            ")-" & _
                            cell.Offset(0, 5).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
```

Comment: Hi Sorry to be a pain